# Message displaying just hover it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Screenshot]

I have a problem with Tooltip hover. What I need is to display the message when I click the button.

Now it's showing on hover.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Order Created Successful">Top</a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what has `java` got to do with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `popover` instead of `tooltip`

```
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Order Created Successful">Top</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>


    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome..Pls tick the answer and upvote if it solved your problem :)